# ASP.NET Application won't notice changes on a .cs-File

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm developing an asp.net application atm and it will be used to insert some data in a database.
Yesterday, I noticed that I've written the wrong table name in one of my insert statements. Ofc I changed it then, **but**..!
After getting the same **"Unknown Column"** exception again and again, I opened the SQL Profiler today and looked at the statement. The statement still tries to insert into the wrong table, but not in the "new" right one, which I've actually written in the code.

Why is the application not noticing changes? I tried to load the website without cache by hitting STRG+F5 for like 125392 times. I also deleted the cache folder, also without success.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: U may want to know that this application is running on a server. Therefore I need to edit the .cs-Files with Notepad because there is no Visual Studio installed on this server.

Comment: are you working with ado.net db connection ??

Comment: then just reset the iis and make sure your db connection is correct i mean mapped db from web config and what changes you have done in db should be same.

Comment: I tried it out, but it's still the same wrong query.

Comment: might be this table using multiple places and you miss some places because this error generally comes when existing connection is opened but you already reset the IIS or somewhere we mapped wrong db

Comment: No there's everything ok with the table, I already checked that. The problem is just this one statement that tries to insert into the wrong table, because it's not getting the changes I've actually written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is running as a website project and not a web application?

If it's running as a website project then editing the .cs files should be picked up. The quickest way to check this would be to introduce a deliberate syntax error to prevent a class from compiling.

Web application projects are compiled before deployment. If there's a .cs file in the web folder for that then it's been deployed by a quick copy-paste rather than a proper publish from Visual Studio and, while the site should work just fine, changes to the .cs files will be ignored. As that's a compiled project you'd need to make the changes somewhere that has access to a compiler (ideally VS on your usual dev machine but I think you could use the command line compiler), then deploy those changes - ideally via a publish to leave the project in a clearer state for the next maintainer :-) If you have to do it manually for whatever reason though, remember you need the .aspx/.ashx etc or .cshtml / .vhbtml files *and* the DLLs.

Comment: Never thought of that. I implemented a syntax error that should have to be thrown. But it won't.
So, how do I change a web application project then?

Comment: @MichaelFreundorfer Edited the answer to clarify, HTH :-)

Comment: So am I right that I just need to run the application on my local dev machine and then copy the edited .cs-files into the server directory? I'm sorry that I'm a little noob ^^

Comment: Firstly, back up the live site just in case! Make the change locally and test it. When you're happy with them go to Build / Publish, make sure it's going in release mode rather than debug, and publish. If that's targeting your local machine then copy the published site onto your server.

Comment: After publishing the project, there are no .cs-files generated. If I paste the generated .aspx-sites into the servers directory, nothing changes.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, there shouldn't be .cs files at that point. It's the DLLs you need, not the .ASPX.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! I could hug u now. It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

.cs files need to be compiled for changes to be added to running library. It is not recommended to edit files directly on the server.